# How do I turn a SQL dataset rows into columns?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sql dataset that I want to convert rows into columns based on the table being grouped by the ID..

Example dataset: (No ID will appear more than 3 times)

| ID | Name | City | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | David | covert | michigan |
| 123 | David | holland | michigan |
| 145 | Bob | austin | texas |
| 145 | Bob | san antonio | texas |
| 145 | Bob | chicago | illinois |

I tried to use the pivot function in sql but that did not work. I actually am not sure how to achieve what I am looking for.

Here is what I want it to look like:

| ID | Name | City_1 | state_1 | city_2 | state_2 | city_3 | state_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | David | covert | michigan | holland | michigan | NULL | NULL |
| 145 | Bob | austin | texas | San antonio | texas | chicago | illinois |

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You might think about creating a json object instead of creating n. number of city, state columns, it will be more flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `row_number` function and conditional aggregation, you may try the following:

```
select ID,
       Name,
       max(case when rn = 1 then City end) as City_1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then State end) as State_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then City end) as City_2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then State end) as State_2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then City end) as City_3,
       max(case when rn = 3 then State end) as State_3
from
(
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by ID, Name order by City) rn
  from table_name 
) t
group by ID, Name
order by ID
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/j308v-iH) on SQL server

Note:

The order of appearing cities and states in the columns (city_1, state_1,...) depends on the alphabetical order of the cities name, if you have another column that specifies that order, you may use it in the order by clause of the row_number function.